# How to make an IconImage in java swing

Tags: java, image, swing

So , I am trying to make a main screen, for  game. In this main screen I want to have some buttons like "play", "exit", "load" etc. But I want to import an image that i made, instead of using a jbutton and whatnot.. Heres the code basicaly..

```
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public MainFrame() {
        super("Main Screen");           
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();            
        ImageIcon pla = new ImageIcon("play.png");

        JButton quit = new JButton("Quit");
        JButton highScores = new JButton("High Scores");
        JButton play = new JButton(pla);
        JButton settings = new JButton("Settings");
        JButton store = new JButton("Store");
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        JButton load = new JButton("Load");

        panel.add(play);
        panel.add(load);
        panel.add(save);
        panel.add(settings);
        panel.add(store);
        panel.add(highScores);
        panel.add(quit);            
        add(panel);
        pack();         
        setSize(getSize());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);       
        requestFocus();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame sw = new MainFrame();
    }    
}
```

But I get this error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:28)
at MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:71)
```

Any advice would be appreciated..Thanks in advance..

EDIT THis is the only code that I have written down, Total of 47 lines, no I did not screw something up, checked multiple times, this was the actual compiler error message.

Comment: Can you tell us the what line is line 28? It is most likely caused by the fact that the image is null.

Comment: panel.add(quit); is in line 28 for some wired reason, could it be that there is something wrong with eclipse?

Comment: Nahh i don't think so. What is line 71 sorry i just want to understand the whole exception

Comment: That's the point, there is no line 71. Total lines of code are 47. I have been writing and erasing many different lines of code but i dont understand how this caqn be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I gave up trying to figure this one out, I just created my projects in seperate folders in the workspace..